# Creating a Year Over Year Line Graph Based on Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, linegraph

I am trying to compare Year over Year revenue for October on a line graph and I have decided my best approach is to create a pivot table with my month column grouped by a month and year format. My value is the sum of revenue. I then clicked on the pivot table and created a line graph that creates a total for all of my data I then filtered my row label "months" for only october and modify my graph data to create two series (2013 & 2014) and modify the Y value to be the revenue value, name to be the year and x axis label to be October, but no data appears on the graph. Why is this happening and what is the best fix?

[image: 2013 chart range]

[image: 2014 chart range]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to graph a **line** for 2013 with one data point, and another **line** for 2014 with another single data point. Excel cannot draw a line for one point (neither can I!)

The Y values for each data series need to be a range rather than a single cell if you want to see a line.

If you wish to see the single data point, use the data series format options to enable markers.